# Horizontal lines crossing timeseries graph with pyplot

Tags: matplotlib, timeserieschart

When I display a timeseries with pyplot I get horizontal lines crossing the chart. it is like the raster lines in old CRT displays. I looked at the data and teh timestamps could not find a reason why this happens in the spline graph. The timeseries is energy demand data. I tried to display other energy data from the web and displayed OK. Any insights? Thanks

Shorter timeseries:

[image: Short timeseries]

Longer timeseries:

[image: longer timeseries]

Comment: Can be that your `x-axis` has repeated values?

Comment: I guess your data is not sorted correctly. I'd suggest having a look at `numpy.argsort` to solve your problem.

Comment: @Joe, yes I tried to make a sanity check on all timestamps ... 100k+ stamps ... and they seemed OK.

Comment: @ThomasKühn, thanks, I will consider `numpy.argsort` if I hit a similar problem. In my case the data was energy demand data and was sorted by datetime.

Answer (score 0):

The problem solved by removing other columns that are not needed. I am sorry I could not inspect all data and I wished to dig up the problem further. It sounds these unneeded columns were confusing the plotter.